# How to save an application setting item

Tags: vb.net, winforms

Good morning, excuse me
I also looked into similar questions but I can not solve the problem anyway.
On a form, on the add Connect window of window, the system and app administrator has the option to 
select the SQL Server available on the system and configure the correct connection string. Once set and validated, it is saved in its app settings set item with the following snippet:

```
If ValidateStringConnection() Then
   My.Settings.MMABooksConnectionString = stNewStringConnection
   My.Settings.Save()
   txtCurrentConnection.Text = My.Settings.MMABooksConnectionString
End If
```

However, the save occurs only at the memory level of the running App, so in a subsequent restart it resumes the value set at the project level and stored in the file:

```
CustomerMaintenanceDB.exe.config
```

I also use the following snippet:

```
My.MySettings.Default("MMABooksConnectionString") = stNewStringConnection
My.MySettings.Default.Save()
```

but nothing is saved in the above file.

Now I ask there is a way for the value of the item to be saved in the above file, so that when the App is subsequently rerun you find the correct connection value without having to intervene again the System Administrator?
Thank you for any helpful advice

Comment: Is this Setting defined in the User or Application scope? (`My.MySettings.Default.MMABooksConnectionString = stNewStringConnection` or `My.Settings.MMABooksConnectionString = stNewStringConnection`).

Comment: nel file xml: CustomerMaintenanceDB.exe.config, c'é:
    <connectionStrings>
        <addname="CustomerMaintenanceDB.My.MySettings.MMABooksConnectionString"
            connectionString="Data Source=ALNB01\DEV;Initial Catalog=MMABooks;Integrated Security=True"
            providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"  />
    </connectionStrings>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right click on the name of your program in Solution Explorer and select Properties. Click the Settings tab.

[image]

Enter MMABooksConnectionString as the Name, select (Connection string) in the Type dropdown and Scope as Appliction. You can scope to application since I don't think this will be changing.

Comment: Ok thank you
I had already done so but to allow to be able to change the Data Source a run time I also had to add a connection property of type string with scope user.
So everything works... Thanks to all of you always very useful and Happy New Year